# Using domain name for Django application deployed on DigitalOcean

Tags: django, deployment, devops

I've created a django application, deployed it on DigitalOcean, and everything works and looks well when using website via IP address. Now I've bought a domain and want to use it for my application, but don't know what to do. First of all I've added my domain name to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `settings.py`, then DigitalOcean's DNS servers added to site where I bought domain. But app doesn't work via domain name yet. Here are my codes:

`settings.py`:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['64.225.1.249', 'forexample.az']
```

`nginx`:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_ip_address (not domain, maybe here I should write domain name ?);

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/my/_username//myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/my/_username/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, domain name is required in server nginx section: `server_name 1.1.1.1 my.domain.com;` Other option -  make it for any domain `listen 80 default_server;`

Comment: @OlegRusskin but what about ```proxy_pass``` ? Depending on its value errors change between ```502``` and ```400```, what is right value ?

Comment: 400 should be response from python (uwsgi? gunicorn?). Try also adding `proxy_set_header Host $host;` in location section near proxy_pass.

Comment: @OlegRusskin I've already added that line, Oleg, don't know why my application works well with an ip address, but when trying to link domain name, it stucks.

Comment: If the domain name on the config wont work, check that it can be resolved by the linux machine (strainght up nslookup it) if the domain name wont work on your browser its because your workstation is the one with resolutions issues, in any case check dns provider (if applicable) and the /etc/host files in both the linux machine and your workstation

Comment: Also, add local ips (localhost, 127.0.0.1, etc on machine) to allowed_hosts.